# django rest framework dynamic related object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Problem** - I have a REST server using django-rest-framework (django v1.7.7, django-rest-framework v3.1.1). In the notifications, I let a user know if they've received a new friend request, or have earned a new badge. There are other notification types as well, but this simple example can explain my problem.

In my GET response, I want to get the notification with a dynamic related object, which is determined by type. if the type is `friendreq` then I want the relatedObject to be a User instance, with a UserSerializer. If the type is `badge`, I want to have the relatedObject be a Badge instance, with a BadgeSerializer.

***Note***: I already have these other serializers (UserSerializer, BadgeSerializer).

Below is what I am wanting to achieve in a response:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Some Title",
    "type": "friendreq"
    "relatedObject": {
        // this is the User instance. For badge it would be a Badge instance
        "id": 1,
        "username": "foo",
        "email": "foo@bar.com",
    }
}
```

And here are what I have for models and serializer:

```
# models.py
class Notification(models.Model):
    """
    Notifications are sent to users to let them know about something. The 
    notifications will be about earning a badge, receiving friend request,
    or a special message from the site admins.
    """
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('badge', 'badge'),
        ('friendreq', 'friend request'),
        ('system', 'system'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="user")
    related_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)


# serializers.py
class NotificationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    if self.type == "badge":
        related_object = BadgeSerializer(
            read_only=True,
            queryset=Badge.objects.get(id=self.related_id)
        )
    elif self.type == "friendreq":
        related_object = FriendRequestSerializer(
            read_only=True,
            queryset=FriendRequest.objects.get(id=self.related_id)
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Notification
```

This code does not work but hopefully it explains what I'm trying to accomplish and the direction I'm trying to go. Maybe that direction is completely wrong and I should be trying to accomplish this by using some other method.

Another option I tried would be to use a `SerializerMethodField` and perform this in a method, but that seemed not as clean for this case of trying to return a Serialized object based upon another field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're going to want to use is the `.to_representation()` approach mentioned here in the DRF documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#generic-relationships